# ASP.NET Core with Angular 7 template connect to SQL Server Express database to read table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, ado.net

I've created an application in Visual Studio Community, ASP.NET Core, with the Angular template. I upgraded Angular of my project to v7.

I tried to follow this example [this c-sharpcorner link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-with-asp-net-core-using-angular-5-and-ado-net/)

Issue is when I try to connect to the server using `https://localhost:44367/api/Employee/Index`, an exception of not being able to connect to the server is thrown.

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

So I created the table and procedures in SQL Server, checked their existence.
Server is started, and configured as in [this msdn link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/).

I enabled TCP/IP, and added a new rule to the firewall to allow all TCP ports requests from local domain.

My `Employee.cs` was modified with the name of the actual project.

My `EmployeeDataAccessLayer.cs` was modified with the name of the actual project and the name of a connection string tested with an ADO.Net entity data model.

I also added the connection string to the `web.config`.

I added the controller where I changed only the name of the project.

In the service with which I inject the code in my Angular app, `empservice.service.ts`, I met some difficulties because I do not know hot to modify the functions below to use HttpClient (map (rxjs) on observable of Http doesn't work). So I commented the code right after the constructor ended.

The service is registered in the app as provider.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
myAppUrl: string = "";
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
}
//getEmployees() {
//  return this.httpClient.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Employee/Index')
//        .map((response: Response) => response.json()
//        .catch(this.errorHandler));
//}

//getEmployeeById(id: number) {
//    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/Details/" + id)
//        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
//        .catch(this.errorHandler)
//}
```

Question 1
It is wrong to expect https://localhost:44367/api/Employee/Index to give the content from the table? ( the implementation of the controller isn't enough?)
Question 2
Can you help me adapt the code from the service above to get the data inside the Angular app?

Comment: Can you limit the code to what is needed in the question? It will be easier to read and answer it that way

Comment: I limited the code as much as I think I can do.

Comment: It's great that you included so many details, but on your next question you can also try to post a very concise question (for instance the error and the connection string). This way, probably more people will read the question and then you can add detail as people request it.

Comment: Thank you very much, is great you spend your time to advice me, but I cut the initial post to a third, I really didn't know what to cut. This way next persons that has this to do, will not waste 4 days, like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous tries and fails, going back to most basic stuff, which I didn't learned, cause I did something else at school, I noticed in a post that to access a database, **you must connect first to it through your program, Visual studio, using server explorer**. **Since the connection string I was trying to use, was not opened in Visual Studio, I couldn't connect to the database.**

As for the second question, the answer is something similar with this:

```
export class EmployeeService {
employees: Observable<Employees[]>;
newemployee: Employees;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
getEmployees() {
return this.http.get<Employee[]>(baseUrl + 'Employees');
}
etc...
}
```

I might edit this post, after I mastered this process. For the moment this is my basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error:

> SqlException: ... The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct ...

and the connectionString:

```
string connectionString = "data source = DESKTOP - RBLIODU\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog = Employees; integrated security = True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
```

I would suggest you to change the server name to `(localhost)` or `DESKTOP-RBLIODU` (without spaces).

Like that:

```
string connectionString = "data source=(localhost)\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog = Employees; integrated security = True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
```

Good luck!